# Creative CSS Solution. Highlighting all elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

I am trying to come up w/ a creative solution for highlighting a bunch of elements when a button has hovered.

Right now in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5jv28o7m/

When you hover copy the "1" div next to it highlights.

What I would like is for `"Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3" and "Element 4"` to highlight when the copy button has hovered. Does anyone know a creative arrangement of CSS selectors that could accomplish this? I am trying to solve this w/ an only CSS solution.

```css
.list {
  flex: 0;
  display: flex;
  width:  200px;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: pink;
}

.listHeader {
  flex: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:  row;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 2px;
}

.copyButton {
  flex: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.copyButton:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.copyableElement {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 2px;
}

.copyableElement:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.copyButton:hover ~ .copyableElement {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="listHeader">
    <div style="flex: 1;"></div>
    <div class="copyButton">Copy</div>
    <div class="copyableElement">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="copyableElement">Element 1</div>
  <div class="copyableElement">Element 2</div>
  <div class="copyableElement">Element 3</div>
  <div class="copyableElement">Element 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you hover the mouse cursor over copy, do you want to select systemically, or apply hover to all?

Comment: While the link to your JS Fiddle is appreciated that does not replace the need for that code to be in your question, please edit your question to include the code (ideally as a Stack Snippet). Though to answer your question no, CSS can't do this since it would require a parent-selector.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the HTML Structure little bit:

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="listHeader">
    <div style="flex: 1;"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="copyButton">Copy<span class="copyableElement">1</span></div>
  <div class="copyableElement">Element 1</div>
  <div class="copyableElement">Element 2</div>
  <div class="copyableElement">Element 3</div>
  <div class="copyableElement">Element 4</div>
</div>
```

And this css also:

```
.copyableElement {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 2px;
  float: right;
}
```

You can check my codepen: https://codepen.io/Mithunjack/pen/OJMKWRv?editors=1100
Please let me know if you are stuck anywhere!! Happy Coding!!